# PHP5 subdomains not working after domain wide switch to PHP5 FastCGI

Tags: php, session, fastcgi

Until last week I had a working configuration of my managed server that was set up to run under PHP4 while all the subdomains ran PHP5 (everything else was a typical LAMP configuration). So it looked like this:

**PHP4 (globally set):**

- www.myDomain.com

**PHP5 (via .htaccess and php.ini):**

- symfony.myDomain.com
- magento.myDomain.com
- reviveAdserver.myDomain.com

Now I finally updated the global configuration to PHP5.3 FastCGI and all the subdomains stopped working. I disabled the .htaccess and php.ini settings too - to no success :-(

**The behaviour is as follows:**

1. Calling the first page in a session will work
2. Every subsequent call will return a **"500 Internal Server Error"** until I clean all cookies and start with step 1 again.

As far as I can tell no error logs are written. The concerned projects are all major well known applications (including a Magento installation which - luckily - is still in development). I tried a new install of the *Revive AdServer* which should support FastCGI - but it shows the same behaviour again.

I am absulutely at the end of my knowledge and so hoping you guys have an idea what it could be.

Comment: Check your Apache error logs for the 500 errors. It would take some custom configuring to **not** log those errors

Comment: Also, *"finally updating"* to PHP 5.3 is like saying *"I finally updated to Windows XP"*. 5.5.12 is the current stable release.

Comment: There's nothing helpful there (at least not for me): for the 1st request it says status 200 and for the 2nd one status 500. Nothing more :-( Well, the returned size differs...

Comment: That's the **access** log. You want the **error** log

Comment: Well, it's 5.3.19, it's what my provider offers. I think I could use 5.4 but the whole main project has been testet with 5.3. so I'm not to keen on taking risks.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I should have specified: although the error log is up to date, there's nothing in there (except non-related stuff like 404s). That's why I had a look in the access log.

Comment: *"I'm not to keen on taking risks"* ~ speaking of taking risks ~ http://php.net/releases/5_3_20.php

Comment: Wow, now that's interesting. Thanx! I'll have a look into that.

Comment: You may have virtual-host specific error logs. Keep looking

Comment: Phil, may I ask you a last time about the PHP version you would recommend? I ran into difficulties today since one of my major programs (the Revive Adserver) refused all PHP5.4x subversions that my provider currently offers.

So right now as a workaround: if you had only the choice between 5.3STABLE (currently .19) or 5.3LATEST (currently .26), which one would you chose for a productive environment?

Comment: Seems [Revive only supports PHP 5.4.20+](http://www.revive-adserver.com/support/requirements/) due to a bug in prior versions. I'd find a new host. If they can't support current, stable PHP releases, they aren't worth hanging on to.

Comment: I thought you'd give that answer ;-) And I'll keep it in mind! But right now I can't - too many open tasks, everything urgent. But I could at least decide between STABLE or LATEST. For me not beeing experienced in webhosting STABLE sounds safer for a productive server. But I assume you would go with LATEST?

Comment: Well, the latest (and **last**) 5.3 release from PHP was [5.3.27](http://php.net/releases/5_3_27.php), released on 11th July, 2013. I would ignore any labels your provider is adding (like *STABLE* and *LATEST*) and use the latest version available. PHP doesn't announce releases that aren't *stable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying EVERY(!!!) possible variation of my default php.ini settings in a sandbox I found the following setting to be the reason:

```
session.auto_start = On
```

This seems to be an incompatible setting for at least Magento 1.8 as well as for the Revive Adverver. Both stopped showing the erroneous behaviour as soon as I changed that. As for symfony I can not yet tell, but I guess it won't matter much as symfony doesn't come as a "ready-to-use" anyway.

Just as foot note and for people who run into the same kind of behaviour: Revive Adverver generated the following error.log:

> PHP Fatal error: 
>   OX_Admin_UI_Install_InstallController::initInstallStatus() [ox-admin-ui-install-installcontroller.initinstallstatus]:
>   The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an
>   incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition
>   "OX_Admin_UI_Install_InstallStatus" of the object you are
>   trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or
>   provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition  in
>   /lib/OX/Admin/UI/Install/InstallController.php on line 134